# Syntax Trigger after update rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm searching for a correct syntaxt for a after update trigger with a rollback:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER UpdatePlayer ON Players
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    IF EXISTS(select * from PlayerContract where id in (select id from deleted))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('No update',16,1)
        ROLLBACK 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'UPDATE'
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(500)
            SELECT  @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)
END CATCH
END
```

When i try a insert, i get the follow error:
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: if you catch the ´no update´ error you raised, why do you rollback after? All you need is the rollback of the catch block.

Comment: yess it's sql-server!

Comment: What it is that you are trying to do? you selecting id from `deleted` but you are using `AFTER UPDATE` instead of `AFTER DELETE`. Update your question with your what you are trying to accomplish and there might be a better way.